# Bold emphasize parts of text

Tags: bold

I have a pdf document made in latex. I have to make a new document following the same template but I only have the pdf, not the source `.tex` file.

Some important words/sentences are "boldly emphasized" but I don't know which command I have to use to do this. (not with the `\emph` cmd)

[image: Example]

An example can be found in the image above (launchRiskEstimation, sensorData and receivedAt)

Comment: This is not bold but mono-spaced font. Try `\texttt{<your text>}` or `{\ttfamily <your text>}`. [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: And, when you do want bold, the command is `\textbf`.

Comment: Still, it would be great to make some “semantic” command like `\emph`, for instance `\DeclareTextFontCommand\code{\ttfamily\mdseries\upshape}`.

Comment: @Manuel Can you make that an answer please?

Answer (score 3):

Still, it would be great to make some “semantic” command like `\emph`, for instance `\DeclareTextFontCommand\code{\ttfamily\mdseries\upshape}`, and then use `\code{whatever}`.